# Adding Grid with custom control to WPF TabControl programmatically doesn't appear

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I'm working on a WPF application and am trying to add a custom control as TabItems programmatically to a TabControl.  I create a Grid and place the custom control inside the grid before adding the grid as a Content to the TabItem.  Here is what I have defined in the XAML:

```
        <TabControl x:Name="studentTabControl" Margin="5">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                            <Grid x:Name="Panel">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                                  Margin="10,2"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem x:Name="student1TabItem" Tag="1" Visibility="Visible">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Student #1" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="student2TabItem" Tag="2" Visibility="Visible">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Student #2" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="student3TabItem" Tag="3" Visibility="Visible">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Student #3" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="student4TabItem" Tag="4" Visibility="Visible">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Student #4" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="student5TabItem" Tag="5" Visibility="Visible">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Student #5" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="student6TabItem" Tag="6" Visibility="Visible">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Student #6" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

I have the Visibility set to Visible explicitly for debugging purposes.  I plan to collapse all the TabItems that shouldn't be visible at runtime and make each one Visible when a particular tab is needed.  The tabs should come and go based on runtime requirements.

Here is the code that will create the Grids and custom control and place them in the TabItems.

```
            foreach (var tab in studentTabs.Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, Index = i }))
        {
            string gridName = "student" + (tab.Index + 1).ToString() + "Grid";
            string tabName = "student" + (tab.Index + 1).ToString() + "Tab";
            var tabitem = (TabItem)this.FindName(tabName + "Item");
            //var grid = (Grid)this.FindName(gridName);
            // if (grid != null && tabitem != null)

            if (tabitem != null)
            {
                Grid grid = new Grid()
                {
                    Name = gridName,
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray)
                };
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });

                Controls.StudentTabControl tabControl = new Controls.StudentTabControl()
                {
                    Name = tabName + "Control",
                    TabStudentNumber = (tab.Index + 1).ToString(),
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    Width = 1180,
                    Height = 1120,
                    Margin = new Thickness(5),
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
                };
                grid.Children.Add(tabControl);
                Grid.SetColumn(tabControl, 0);
                Grid.SetRow(tabControl, 0);
                tabitem.Content = grid;

                studentTabs[tab.Index] = tabControl;

            }
            this.studentTabControl.UpdateLayout();
        }
```

The custom control is very complex but it essentially starts with an outer Grid and everything is placed inside of it in XAML.  During runtime, I look at the Visual Tree and I don't see the added Grid and custom control.  I'm not sure what is happening and why I'm losing the added controls from the tree.  I just don't see the problem.

As an aside, I first had the Grid predefined in the TabItems in XAML and tried just creating the custom control and adding that programmatically, but that didn't work.  However, I did see the grids in the Visual Tree.

Finally, I should mention that the window I'm adding everything to is not the main application, it is a separate popup window of type Window.  I do Initialize and create everything before I call Show() on the popup window.

Any info that can be provided would help a great deal.

Comment: I used Border instead of Controls.StudentTabControl and everything showed up in TabControl

Comment: @ASh -- Curious. I wonder if I should also programmatically create the TabItem, place everything in it and then add the TabItems to the TabControl.